# Haskeline throws linking error in stack build

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskeline

I'm trying to build haskell project via `stack build` command, but it throws excepton:

```
--  While building package %some secret project name%-0.1.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /home/%some secret username%/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.7 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0 build lib:%some secret project name% exe:%exe name% --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Also it outputs following error in log file:

```
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build/%secret name%/%secret name% ...
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -ltinfo
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/haskeline-0.8.2/libHShaskeline-0.8.2.a(Terminfo.o)(.text..LsmG9_info+0x76): error: undefined reference to 'set_curterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/haskeline-0.8.2/libHShaskeline-0.8.2.a(Terminfo.o)(.text..LsmG9_info+0xcc): error: undefined reference to 'set_curterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/haskeline-0.8.2/libHShaskeline-0.8.2.a(Terminfo.o)(.text..LsmG9_info+0x147): error: undefined reference to 'set_curterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/haskeline-0.8.2/libHShaskeline-0.8.2.a(Terminfo.o)(.text..LsmG9_info+0x1bb): error: undefined reference to 'set_curterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Lr5WM_info+0xb2): error: undefined reference to 'tigetnum'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Lr5WN_info+0xb2): error: undefined reference to 'tigetflag'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Lr5WO_info+0xb2): error: undefined reference to 'tigetstr'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Ls64w_info+0x354): error: undefined reference to 'tparm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Ls66r_info+0x129): error: undefined reference to 'setupterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Ls66r_info+0x22a): error: undefined reference to 'del_curterm'
/home/messieurme/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4.a(Base.o)(.text..Ls68h_info+0x141): error: undefined reference to 'tputs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

My code haven't any errors in .hs files. Also I can invoke any function (even main) via `stack ghci`and it works fine.
After some researches I found that if I'll remove `haskeline` from dependencies in `%project name%.cabal` file, `stack build` will execute witout any problems.

I use `haskeline` only in app/main.hs and my code is from [this site](http://lambda.inf.elte.hu/haskell/doc/libraries/haskeline-0.7.4.2/System-Console-Haskeline.html). Here it is

```
import System.Console.Haskeline

main :: IO ()
main = runInputT defaultSettings loop
   where
       loop :: InputT IO ()
       loop = do
           minput <- getInputLine "% "
           case minput of
               Nothing -> return ()
               Just "quit" -> return ()
               Just input -> do outputStrLn $ "Input was: " ++ input
                                loop
```

Here is part of .cabal file where I'm adding haskeline:

```
executable hi
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             %Some secret main name%.hs
  ghc-options:         -Wall -Werror -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base >= 4.9 && < 5
                     , %extra deps%
                     , haskeline
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Version of haskeline doesn't matter. I tried to set previous versions and error occured with each of them.
I tried to google problem, but it seems that nobody faced it before or it's too trivial to ask about.
I'm using linux mint, maybe it impacts somehow.
I fully reinstalled stack but problem is still with me. Deleting temporary files like .stack-work within project also didn't help

Comment: Is `libtinfo-dev` installed? The `ld.gold` error indicates that this might be the problem. Otherwise I'd probably ask for help on the `haskeline` issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were due to the missing `libtinfo-dev`. Once I had library installed the problem disappeared. Thanks to the answer in comments